# fixing an unintentional infinite loop

Tags: c++

when i input a random number like 63453462 it responds with "invalid number" but in an infinite loop but if i put a number like 2,000,002 it just says invalid number with no loop. I need help with not making an infinite loop when someone inserts a random number like 2145345665465.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int sum , input , number;                    

cout << "Enter any positive integer that is less than or " ;
cout << "equal to 2,000,000 to determine if it is divisible by 11.";
cout << endl;
cout << "If the number is greater than 99, we use Dodgsons's rule";
cout << endl;
cout << "which determines if it is a factor or not.\n";
cout << endl;
cin  >> input;


   while ((input < 1) || ( input > 2000000 ))
     {
        cout << "Invalid number detected, please enter a positive integer.\n"; 
        cin >> input;
     }  

     number = input;

      while ((input>=100) && (input < 2000000)) 
    {
     sum = input % 10;
     input = input /10 - sum;
     cout << input << endl;
     }

     if (input % 11 == 0)
     cout << "the number is divisible by 11." << endl;
     else 
     cout << "the number is not divisible by 11." << endl;

system ("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, did you inspect this line by line with the debugger?

Comment: `cin` probably enters a `failed` state, causing each following input operation to fail until the issue (not a number, the number is too large, ..) has been resolved (usually by clearing the input buffer).

Answer (score 0):

```
   while ((input < 1) || ( input > 2000000 ))
{
    cout << "Invalid number detected, please enter a positive integer.\n";
    cin >> input;
    cin.clear(); 
}
```

`cin.clear()` will clear any previous state that cause the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly check whether your input operation succeeded. If you enter something that cannot be parsed as an integer, or some value that is more than `INT_MAX` or less than `INT_MIN`, then after

```
cin >> input
```

the stream `std::cin` will enter a failed state, that means the `failbit` is set. After that, each following input operation will also fail, unless you take care of it.

The usual approach here is to clear the input buffer (with the input that could not be handled) and just try again:

```
while (not (cin >> input) or not is_valid(input)) {
  cout << "Invalid input, try again" << endl;
  cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  cin.clear();
}
```

This first does the input operation (`cin >> input`) and checks whether it `not` succeeded, and only if that is not true (i.e. the input operation succeeded) checks whether the input is `not` valid using some `is_valid` function. In that case an error is printed, all characters up to and including the next newline are removed from the stream, and the `failbit` is cleared, in order to allow a new take on getting valid input.

Note, that having two variables of the same type and doing

```
number = input;
```

is useless here, you can directly read into `number` (which is more appropriately named) and drop the variable `input` all together.

Comment: Any reason for taking back the upvote? If there's something missing or wrong, please let me know.